# Are there any commonly-used, efficient Java sort implementations when stability is not a requirement?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

The Java implementation (at least the one I use, which is version 1.8 of JDK from Oracle) uses an stable sort. With stable I'm referring to the algorithm guaranteeing that two objects A and B that are equal according to the sorting criterion preserve their original ordering. However, I have a use case where I am sorting Objects, and I do not need the sort to be stable.

I have also noticed (by profiling) that it would be beneficial for me to optimize this sorting. Since I don't NEED the stable sorting, and I suppose an unstable sorting can be faster, I would like to replace the default sorting here with an unstable (and hopefully faster) sort. Are there any good, well-known implementations that are commonly-used around there? Can you recommend any?

In the worst case implementing an algorithm myself is always an option, but I'd prefer to go for an existing implementation that has already been thoroughly tested and profiled and is widely used. Unfortunately I was not able to find such an implementation though.

EDIT: The reason I wrote that I assume an unstable sort can potentially be faster than a stable sort is because the task of unstable sorting is easier than, or as difficult as, the task of stable sorting. Every solution for stable sorting is also a solution for unstable sorting, but the opposite is not true. I realise that in practice this does not necessarily mean that an unstable sorting algorithm is going to be faster, but it is possible in theory, so I'd like to explore the option

Comment: Quick question - are you looking for a guaranteed O(n log n) unstable sort like heapsort, or a fast-on-the-average-case unstable sort like quicksort?

Comment: What is your evidence that you would benefit from another algorithm ?

Comment: (1) There are no `ArrayLists` or other Collections of primitives.  There are arrays, but that's different.  (2) If there were, how could you tell whether a sort of such a collection was stable?

Comment: Note that since Java 7, the default sort is [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which has worst-case O(N log N) performance, but which does much better on data containing long runs of in-order or reverse-order data.  It's performance characteristics are really pretty impressive.

Comment: Ah right my mistake, I believe I read somewhere earlier that java switches based on the type (I suppose it could still choose to go for an unstable sort in the case of a collection of boxed primitives, like ArrayList<Integer>). But I checked and it doesn't, it always uses Timsort

Still, my guess is that theoretically a sorting algorithm (like QuickSort) could be faster if the requirement of stability is removed, since it may make the sorting task easier (or maybe equally difficult), but never more difficult. I realise that that doesn't guarantee an unstable sort is also faster in practice

Comment: @DennisSoemers You're stating your goal wrong. Your statement *"I would like to replace the default sorting here with an unstable (and hopefully faster) sort"* is confusing. Why do you *require* unstable sort, but leave *faster* optional? Don't you actually want it the other way around? A *faster* sort, whether stable or not! You should ask a different question: *What is the fastest sort I can get in Java, when stability is not a requirement?*

Comment: Assuming that Java implements an array of objects as an array of pointers to objects and that it sorts pointers rather than sorting the data between objects, then timsort is probably faster than quicksort, although timsort will take up more space (for a second array of pointers). I tested with C++ STL, sorting an array of pointers to p-strings, and std::stable_sort (variation of merge sort) is faster than std::sort() (variation of quick sort). Merge sort does more moves (of pointers), but fewer compares (deferencing pointers, comparator calls) than quicksort, so in this case it's faster.

Comment: @Andreas yes that's right. I've edited the question according to your comment and some other comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the various comments, it looks like TimSort (which is the default implementation used by Java for sorting, and is a stable sort) is likely to be one of the best options available.

However, with some more googling around I did find this ["Vergesort"](https://github.com/Morwenn/vergesort) algorithm which may be faster than TimSort. It is implemented in C++ though, but if I find time I may try to port it to Java, benchmark it, and describe results here.

The data I have in particular tends to contain short sequences of ascending or descending elements, which is kind of a combination of the two ''sawtooth'' benchmarks described on the VergeSort page. On those benchmarks, VergeSort was shown to outperform TimSort. These benchmarks in C++ sort plain integers though, and not pointers to data (which is more likely to be the case in Java, as described by rcgldr).

Comment: A few additional notes (being the implementer): vergesort is globally untested for anything else than integer and floating point types; I've currently next to no idea how it performs otherwise. Also, if the runs are smaller than `n / log n` (`n` begin the size of the collection), vergesort might waste time identifying them, then giving up because they're too small and falling back to another algorithm. To get around that, you could try to replace the `n / log n` heuristic by something else, but then I'm not sure how the k-way merge would perform.

Comment: @Morwenn I did not end up trying to implement it for the application I had in mind at the time of asking the question, decided I was more likely to improve the application by spending time in other ways. However, I have moved on to a new research project, where I may again want to play around with high-performance sorting of Java objects with no need for stability. I'll also again expect there to be a lot of structure in the data before sorting (I'll frequently have to re-sort with sorting criteria changing smoothly over time)... so if you're interested, I'll let you know about any results!

Comment: If you end up trying it, I would indeed be interested in seeing the results; I don't always have all the time or motivation in the world to try everything I want, so independent results would be nice, thanks for proposing :)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia has a great table for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)

From what I can read, as Nayuki said, your best bets are Quicksort and Heapsort.

[Here's](https://github.com/pranav-patil/algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/library/algorithms/sorting/HeapSort.java) a quick dirty implementation of Heapsort for you, thanks GitHub.

Of course, if this is meant for your real-life data you want to use, just go with Oracle's sort. Probably it's going to be hard to find a more efficient sort, and its stability is usually moot anyway.

Comment: yes I'm aware of which algorithms there are and their complexities, but I was looking for a well-tested existing implementation instead of rolling out my own. I could give the implementation you linked there a try, but yeah, I'm not sure how likely a ''quicky dirty implementation'' is to be faster than Oracle's implementation. I'll give it a try though, thanks.

Comment: According to the reference you provide Timsort (actually used in java) is quicker in the best and worst cases and performs the same on average compared to both quicksort and heapsort. blocksort seems to be less memory hungry, but that was not of concern in the question. So the correct answer should be: use the default one. In fact, other languages, e.g. python, also use Timsort AFAIK.

Comment: @OlegSklyar I agree, just use the default one. That's what I meant by "Just go with Oracle's sort".

Though this subject can be interesting to learn about, I don't think that's why OP is asking.